# Azure DevOps API - how can I get point id?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Just getting started with automating test results with Azure DevOps API. We are stuck at api-version 5.0 for now, so I won't be able to use newer calls.

When I call
Test; Test Suites; Get Test Cases

```
{{azureapi}}/test/Plans/171434/suites/173613/testcases?api-version=5.0
```

I get back a nice pile of test cases. They have a point assignments section for each case, but not a point id. I need a point id to record my results using Test; Results; Add (I think).

But when I try to get the points for that all the tests in that suite, by calling
Test; Points; List

```
{{azureapi}}/test/Plans/171434/suites/173613/points?api-version=5.0
```

I get

```
{
 "value": [],
 "count": 0
}
```

I don't understand why that count is zero. Do I need to do something to create the points? Am I making the wrong call?
Please remember I am on version 5.0, so I cannot call
Test; Test Point; Get Points List.
Is there a way I can get the point ids for this test suite?

Answer (score 0):

Test with API version 5.0, I can reproduce the same issue. The test point result will not return.

The issue should be related to the API version.

To solve this issue, you can change to use the API version: **api-version=6.0-preview.2**

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/TestPoint?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

In the case, the test points will be returned in API response.

For more info, you can refer to this doc: [Test Point - Get Points List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test-point/get-points-list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)